# Logstash, one json object to multiple ones

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

please my logstash input is the following :

`{"views":[{"name":"a"},{"name":" b"},{"name":" c"}]}`

I just want to insert it into Elasticsearch as 3 documents, not one, but logstash outputs it as one document, please any idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try on  this example:

```
input {
  stdin {
  }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  split { 
    field => "views"
  }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life =)

Comment: please if I want to split using a field within views, as a nested field, what should I do ? @Кирилл Полищук

Comment: try this syntax: 
split {
    field => "[views][nested_views]"
}

Comment: please @Кирилл Полищук, I do have tree levels, I want to split by the 3th level only, I mean I have document for each existing 3th level, this is my filter :
`filter {
if !("splitted_views" in [tags]) {
json {
source => "message"
}
split { 
field => "views"
add_tag => ["splitted_views"]
}
    }
if ( "splitted_views" in [tags] and [views][jobs] ) {
split {
add_tag => ["splitted_jobs"]   
field => "views[jobs]"

}
}
if ( "splitted_jobs" in [tags] and [views][jobs][builds] ) {
split {

field => "views[jobs][builds]"
        }
}
}
`
I'm getting redundant docs, any idea ?